# Lines on a quadric surface

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, euclidean-geometry, projective-geometry

I want to show that:

Let $Q$ be a quadric surface of rank 3 in $\mathbf{P}^3$(over $\mathbf{C}$), then any line in $Q$ must pass through the only singular point of $Q$.

I know that up to a transform of coordinate, we can assume that $Q=\{x_0^2+x_1^2+x_2^2=0\}$ and therefore the singular point is $(0:0:0:1)$. But I have no idea how to proceed. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose for contradiction that some  line $l$ lies on $Q$ ($l\subset Q$) but does not go through the apex (=singular point) $S$ of $Q$.
Then the whole plane $\Pi$ determined by $S$ and $l$ is contained in $Q$ ($\Pi\subset Q$): indeed  for any $L\in l\subset Q$ the line $\overline {SL}$ lies on   $Q$ and $\Pi$ is the union of all those lines $\overline {SL}$ when $L$ runs through $l$.
But any  quadric   containing a plane (here $\Pi\subset Q$)  has rank $\leq 2$ : contradiction to the hypothesis that $Q$ has rank $3$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's very clear and I understand it :)

Comment: Dear user 243987,  I'm glad the answer was useful to you